# How to arrange elements in a numpy array in descending order?

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I created and reshaped an array with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,0.5,0],[1,0.3,0]])
b=a.reshape(6,1)
```

Now, how do I rearrange the elements in array b in descending order? I want to get values that go from 1 to 0 such that I get in a (6,1) numpy array:

> [1.]
> [1.]
> [0.5]
> [0.3]
> [0.]
> [0.]

Sorry, the array didn't come out in a vertical arrangement.
I tried other reordering or sorting methods found online but they either reversed the order of the array, or didn't work. I also tried -np.sort(-b) and that did not work too.

Comment: You could use `np.sort(b, axis=0)[::-1]`. Biggest issue seems to be missing axis=0.